# Unable to upload pdf and word files through UniSharp / laravel-filemanager laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I am using UniSharp / laravel-filemanager to upload files and images . locally in the Xampp server it is working fine. but on the live server (cPanel) it allow me to select only images. I want to upload pdf and word files and also videos. how to do theses modifications inUniSharp / laravel-filemanager. how to change the `filemanager?type=image` to  `filemanager?type=file`.
screen shoot of the file manager is attached here with
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9mV4.png)

Thank you

`filemanager?type=image` to  `filemanager?type=file`.